# How Do I Make A Shaped UI Button on Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am making an app on Xcode and I am using UI Buttons. I am using image background and put a picture of a whale in PNG form. I want it so that when I press on the whale it will increment a counter. I do not want to increment the counter if the background/transparent part of the button is pressed. I only want to increment the counter if the inside part of the whale is pressed. How do I do that? A UIButton always responds to touches within its entire bound, how do I remove that restriction?

Comment: Is this really necessary on a real iOS device where touching the button with a finger is far less precise than clicking on the button in the simulator with a mouse pointer?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using a UIButton is to use A CAShapeLayer. Have it's content be your whale - I agree with @rmaddy, hope it's large enough! - attach a tap recognizer to the view, and use the hitTest() method of the CALayer to detect if it was tapped.

Answer (score -1):

Render a Bezier path in the draw function of a UIControl subclass

Comment: This has no affect on whether the tap is registered or not within the image.

Comment: Well skeeter, a tiny bit of thought on your part would inform you that my answer is pointing the OP in the correct direction rather than giving a blow by blow recipe. For others besides down voting maddy reading, UIControl has functions to override for taps wherein you can check to see if the tap point is within the bezier path or not.

Comment: The question is asking how to deal with handling the touches only within the image shape. How does stating to render a bezier path help answer that? It doesn't. That unrelated info does not point the OP in the right direction.